# Creación de un Stored Procedure para comparar datos iguales

Tags: sql-server

Buenas  tardes tengo la siguiente consulta en *SQL Server*

```
select l.Codigo, e.Clave, u.Cantidad, L.IdLocalidad, e.IdEstilo from Localidad l 
inner join UnitarioLocalidad ul on l.IdLocalidad = ul.IdLocalidad
inner join Unitario u on ul.IdUnitario = u.IdUnitario
inner join Producto p on u.IdProducto = p.Idproducto 
inner join Estilo e on p.IdEstilo = e.IdEstilo where l.Codigo = 'PREC26';
```

**Trae los siguientes datos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora tome el dato de **IdEstilo** de la primera fial que es **7046** y realice otra consulta que se muestra a continuación

```
SELECT Codigo FROM Localidad l
inner join RecepcionDetalleAbierta rda on rda.IdLocalidadAlmacenado = l.IdLocalidad WHERE IdEstilo = 7046;
```

**Y arrojo el siguiente resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo es que quiero hacer un stored procedure donde me compare cada uno de  los **IdEstilo** que arrojó la primera consulta y si todos traen el mismo  **Codigo** del campo de la segunda consulta que me arroje un verdadero de lo contrario falso

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

verifica ahora, si la puedes utilizar, ya que compara si todos los idEstilo traen el mismo codigo

```
select
     l.Codigo, 
     e.Clave, 
     u.Cantidad, 
     L.IdLocalidad, 
     e.IdEstilo 
from Localidad l 
inner join UnitarioLocalidad ul on l.IdLocalidad = ul.IdLocalidad
inner join Unitario u on ul.IdUnitario = u.IdUnitario
inner join Producto p on u.IdProducto = p.Idproducto 
inner join Estilo e on p.IdEstilo = e.IdEstilo 
where l.Codigo = all (
select
     l.Codigo, 
from Localidad l 
inner join UnitarioLocalidad ul on l.IdLocalidad = ul.IdLocalidad
inner join Unitario u on ul.IdUnitario = u.IdUnitario
inner join Producto p on u.IdProducto = p.Idproducto 
inner join Estilo e on p.IdEstilo = e.IdEstilo and l.Codigo = 'PREC26';

)
```

Comment: Corrí la consulta y no me lealizó nada aparte quiero que todo se haga con base a PREC26

Comment: Publica las estructuras de las tablas para poder ayudarte